# POST request not working in Ajax jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I have a `Django` application where I am trying to open `index2.html` from `index.html` on `button click` event. Basically, I am using 2 procedures in order to fulfil this simple task

1. Form with submit button (Button 1)
2. Ajax (Button 2)

First one seems to work fine but `Ajax` is not working. On clicking, `Button 2` nothing seems to happen. Can anybody tell me whats going on, any help would be appreciated.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h2>Index</h2>

    <form method="post" action="/index2/">
        <button type="submit" >Button 1</button>
        <input type="button" id="btn" name="btn" value="Button 2" />
    </form>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $("#btn").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/index2/',
                data: {}
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**index2.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Index 2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Index 2</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.shortcuts import render

@csrf_exempt
def index(request):

    return render(request, "index.html")

@csrf_exempt
def index2(request):

    return render(request, "index2.html")
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('index/', views.index, name='index'),
    path('index2/', views.index2, name='index2'),
]
```

Comment: Why don't you use a simple link: `<a href="index2.html">to Index 2</a>` instead of ajax?

Comment: Nothing happens in ajax because you've not written any `success` handler. It sends request but does not handle the response.

Comment: @KoshVery Its a simplified version of a problem that I am facing in my project

Comment: @KoshVery On clicking `Button 2` control seems to go in `index2()` function in `views.py`, I have checked it by using `print` statement. But it is failing to render `index2.html`.

Comment: Looks like you do not completely understand how ajax works. So you have wrong expectations on your code. I'd suggest you reading  `jQuery.ajax()` and `XMLHttpRequest` documentation.